# Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class

Tags: magento2

I am getting this error on my controller

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class
>   Magenest\QuickBooksOnline\Controller\Adminhtml\AbstractQueue in
>   magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:116

how can we fix this error ?

Answer (score 0):

You must check a factory code, because it is impossible to create an object of abstract class in PHP. Seems like somewhere in your di an abstract class defined as a real class, but you must use some class which extends that abstract class. Try to search through all `.xml` files where is `Magenest\QuickBooksOnline\Controller\Adminhtml\AbstractQueue` used.

Comment: how we ca n do this???

Comment: @dfsd check update please. I'll recommend you to use `grep` or another kind of search to detect where that class is used.